# Laravel eloquent whereIn with one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel, I can use many where rules as an array a run one query to the database using laravel eloquent `where` method to get needed result.

**Code:**

```
$where = [];
$where[] = ['user_id', '!=', null];
$where[] = ['updated_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')];
if($request->searchTerm) {
    $where[] = ['title', 'like', '%' . $request->searchTerm . '%'];
}
Model::where($where)->get();
```

**Question part:**

Now I need to use Laravel Eloquent method `whereIn` with array params to get needed result with one query.

I tried by **looping** method but with many queries to the database.

**Code:**

```
$model = new Model;
$whereIn = []; 

$whereIn[] = ['date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(10)];
$whereIn[] = ['user_role', 'candidate'];

if (!empty($scope) && is_array($scope)) {
    $whereIn[] = ['user_id', $scope];
}
if(is_array($employment) && !empty($employment)) {
    $whereIn[] = ['employment', $employment];
}
if(is_array($experience) && !empty($experience)) {
    $whereIn[] = ['experience', $experience];
}

foreach ($whereIn as $v) {
    $model = $model->whereIn($v[0], $v[1]);
}

dump($model->get());
```

First I tired `$model->whereIn($whereIn)->get()` but it's return error. It's possible get results with one query using `whereIn` without looping?

**Note:** My `$whereIn` array will be dynamic array!

Comment: Your code must work, what is the error that you have?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki my code work for many query but I need solution for one query

Comment: @AndreasHunter looking at your variable names, you need a `where`  and not a `whereIn`.

Comment: @AndreasHunter You are querying a `where` on  `$model = new Model;`?

Comment: @vivek_23 I showed an example that with the `where()` method you can use an array with many conditions and send a single query to the database and get the result. On a given question, I ask whether you can do the same with the `whereIn()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`whereIn` is a query builder function so you can't use it on the model directly. Instead you should create a query builder instance. I also suggest you use `when` instead of the `if` statements:

```
$models = Model::when(!empty($scope) && is_array($scope), function ($query) use ($scope) {
    $query->whereIn('user_id', $scope);
})->when(!empty($employment) && is_array($employment), function ($query) use ($employment) {
    $query->whereIn('employment', $employment);
})->when(!empty($experience) && is_array($experience), function ($query) use ($experience) {
    $query->whereIn('experience', $experience);
})->get(); 

dump($models);
```

`when` essentially runs the function when the first parameter is true. There's more detail in the documentation under [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `$whereIn` variable is an array of arrays it will work like :

```
$model->whereIn($whereIn[0][0], $whereIn[0][1])->get();
```

If it just a simple array then you can use :

```
$model->whereIn($whereIn[0], $whereIn[1])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do in Eloquent

```
$model = Model::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Or using Query builder then :

```
$model = DB::table('table')->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```